# Java.exe exited with code 1 (Xamarin C#)

Tags: java, c#, xamarin.android

I try to compile Android app and has this error

```
   Note: obj\Release\android\src\mono\com\google\android\gms\maps\GoogleMap_OnMyLocationChangeListenerImplementor.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
1>  Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1>  Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
1>  Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1>  79 warnings
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2118,3): error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 1.
```

I updated all packages and clear project. But have this error again

How I can solve this issue